# Timed out in sqlmap

Tags: sql-injection, databases, sqlmap

I detect a `sqli` vulnerability in a target url using `sqlmap`. Now when I try this I always get "`connection timed out to the target URL`":

```
./sqlmap.py -u targetURL --dbs
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: It means that the server at the other end isn't responding in a reasonable time - might be that it's fallen over, or that a WAF or IDS has detected unusual traffic and blocked the source IP.

Comment: Thanks, what's your idea to get DBs in this situation? Is it helpful use the above command with --tor switch,?@Matthew

Comment: Depends on the specific reason for the failure - you'd need to investigate that before trying to work around it. For example, if the site has fallen over, it doesn't matter what you do, since you won't get a response. Worth asking the site owner if you're in a pen testing situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a server you own, look at the logs. If you do not, you may have fallen into a honeypot/honeyport/active countermeasures url or otherwise been detected by Intrusion Detection or a Web Application Firewall - something like Fail2Ban may have gotten you.  If you're a pentester, talk to your client - if they want you to proceed, they may have to whitelist you.

You can always try going through a proxy, see if that connection succeeds.

Comment: I have the payloads for injection point in url is detected by sqlmap. but when I try this: sqlmap.py -u myURL --dbs, the result is timed out. Is it possible I use the payloads for manual sql injection and access to DB?

Comment: Well, can you get to the website with a regular browser?   If not, this is time to talk to your client.

Comment: Yes, I can get it